# Почему линия рисуется не правильно?

Tags: html, svg

```html
<svg height='6' width='200' xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <polygon points='0,0 97,0 103,6 200,6' />
</svg>
```

По-идее должно получиться вот так, но не выходит.
В чем проблема? А при добавлении `viewBox='0 0 200 6'` вообще пропадает изображение.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы забыли покрасить строку `stroke="black"`
 Добавил к высоте `2px` так, как толщина линии по умолчанию `1px`, две линии - `2px`.

```html
<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="200px" height="8px" viewBox="0 -1 200 8" version="1.1" >
<path d="m-0.2-0.5 97.8 0 4.6 7 97.8-0.2" style="fill:none;stroke:black"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Что-то не то http://prntscr.com/j4g5pe

Comment: @uzi_no_uzi путь значит, так нарисован, хотите перерисую

Comment: тег не polygon, а polyline должен быть, раз хотите линии.

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, если можно, было бы не плохо) А то я что-то запутался

Comment: @uzi_no_uzi сделано